# Program initialization failed (0xc0150002) when start a program depend on a third party dll

Tags: visual-c++, dll, visual-studio-2005, side-by-side, winsxs

When I write a c++ program (such as B3DTest.exe) depend on a third party dll(such B3DViews.dll) (the vendor is small company). The program that I wrote is very simple just to test one function in the dll. When I start my program (the needed header file, .lib files and .dll file are linked). I come across the problem below.

```
The application failed to initialize properly (0xc0150002). Click on OK to terminate 
the application.
```

I find out that the program exit before enter my main function. the out put of the vs2008 IDE is

```
LDR: LdrpWalkImportDescriptor() failed to probe e:\tlh1987\vs2008projects\B3DTest\Debug\B3DViews.dll
for its manifest, ntstatus 0xc0150002
```

I put the program and the dll in an other target computer and it works fine. So I think it must be something wrong with my computer. I searched the event log and it says below for three event

```
EventID: 32
Description: Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC80.CRT could not be found and Last Error was The referenced     
assembly is not installed on your system.
EventID: 59
Description: Resolve Partial Assembly failed for Microsoft.VC80.CRT. Reference error message: The    
referenced assembly is not installed on your system.
EventID: 59
Description: Generate Activation Context failed for Generate Activation Context
E:\tlh1987\vs2008projects\B3DTest\Debug\B3DViews.dll. Reference error message: The operation completed
successfully.
```

I search The Internet to find out that someone fix a similar problem by installing `Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable Package` and the `Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86).`
I download the two files and installed it. However, it couldn't work! 
Another solution on the internet is Put the files of Microsoft.VC80.CRT folder which include 3 dll and Microsoft.VC80.MFC folder (also include 4 dll) and finally the correspond manifest files in the dir of B3DTest.exe (my program). However, It still didn't work!  But something has changed the `event log` where there is only 1 `event error` which says below:

```
EventID: 59
Description: Generate Activation Context failed for Generate Activation Context
E:\tlh1987\vs2008projects\B3DTest\Debug\B3DViews.dll. Reference error message: The operation completed
successfully.
```

Somebody told me that may be the version of the VC80.CRT and the VC80.MFC in my computer didn't match the version number in the `B3DViews.dll` (which is distributed by the vendor). Then I open the `B3DViews.dll` with emacs.exe and search the manifest attached to the dll. It says below:

```
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
<dependency>
  <dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC80.CRT" version="8.0.50727.6195"    
  processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"></assemblyIdentity>
  </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC80.MFC" version="8.0.50727.6195" 
processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"></assemblyIdentity>
</dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC80.CRT" version="8.0.50608.0" 
  processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"></assemblyIdentity>
  </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC80.MFC" version="8.0.50608.0" 
  processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"></assemblyIdentity>
  </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
</assembly>
```

the version number made me confused. How can it is `8.0.50727.6195` as well as `8.0.50608.0` It think it should be one version number (not two as showed above).  I find the Microsoft.VC80.CRT dlls and the Microsoft.VC80.MFC dlls and also the correspond manifest files (all the version numbers is `8.0.50727.6195` in the C:\Windows\WinSxS and put it in the dir the same as `B3DTest.exe` (my program). It couldn't work either. 
    In order to figure out the problem.  I used the `Dependency Walker for Win32 (x86)` to profile my program i.e. `B3DTest.exe`. It says below:

```
Started "B3DTEST.EXE" (process 0x680) at address 0x00400000.  Successfully hooked module.
Loaded "NTDLL.DLL" at address 0x7C920000.  Successfully hooked module.
Loaded "KERNEL32.DLL" at address 0x7C800000.  Successfully hooked module.
DllMain(0x7C920000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "NTDLL.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x7C920000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "NTDLL.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
DllMain(0x7C800000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "KERNEL32.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x7C800000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "KERNEL32.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
Injected "DEPENDS.DLL" at address 0x08370000.
DllMain(0x08370000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "DEPENDS.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x08370000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "DEPENDS.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
Loaded "B3DVIEWS.DLL" at address 0x10000000.  Successfully hooked module.
LDR: LdrpWalkImportDescriptor() failed to probe e:\tlh1987\vs2008projects\b3dtest\debug\B3DViews.dll 
for its manifest, ntstatus 0xc0150002
First chance exception 0xC0150002 (Unknown) occurred in "NTDLL.DLL" at address 0x7C9873BE.
**Second chance exception 0xC0150002 (Unknown) occurred in "NTDLL.DLL" at address 0x7C9873BE.**
Exited "B3DTEST.EXE" (process 0x680) with code -1072365566 (0xC0150002).
```

It drives me crazy. I wan't to figure it out. any help will appreciated!
This(http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=408061) may help to the problem. But I can not figure it out by reading it.
    my system is windows xp sp3 and I using VS2008. I didn't install VS2005.

Comment: That manifest is messed up, looks like that DLL was linked with code that was built with a beta version of VS2005.  You'll need to get a better build, contact the vendor or author for support.

Comment: @HansPassant But it works well on my colleague's computer. I just want it work. it may be difficult to contact the vendor.

Comment: It seems that only my computer failed when starting the program.

Comment: Find it hard to believe no-one's upvoted this one just for relative effort alone: +1

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out somehow. with the help of this Q&A

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nb-NO/vssetup/thread/fa559cb7-eabc-4f41-a3bc-84ed7ae089fc

first, I uninstalled all the `Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable Package`

second, I installed `Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)` directly. It didn't work either, but when I installed

[Visual C++ 2005 Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package MFC Security Update](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=26347)

It just works. It seems that the Update del the old version of `Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable Package`, then make the new one (the sp1 one) to work.

Answer (score 1):

First, I uninstalled all the Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable Package
second, I installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86) directly. It didn't work either, but when I installed

Visual C++ 2005 Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package MFC Security Update

It just works

Answer (score 1):

`0xC0150002L` is `STATUS_SXS_CANT_GEN_ACTCTX`. The tool for debugging activation context issues is `SxsTrace`. Try this:

```
touch program.exe
SxsTrace Trace -logfile:SxsTrace.etl
[run program.exe]
SxsTrace Parse -logfile:SxsTrace.etl -outfile:SxsTrace.txt
```

SxsTrace.txt will contain the name of the assembly that is referenced and can't be found.

Comment: This, Good Sir, was invaluable! Thanks for posting this.